# Authentication in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a User model, UserServices and through the login page I want to authenticate a registered user.

 Can you help me to write the method to be used in Authentication Controller?

```
<fieldset><legend>Authentication</legend>
<form:form action="login.htm"  commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                path="userName" /></FONT></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                path="password" /></FONT></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @Logan these two links helped me the direction I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @user1577291 If the answers were useful don't hesitate to upvote them and to accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already use spring, you can easily add [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) to handle user authentication and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a sample tutorial how to add spring security to your application.
http://blog.rajithdelantha.com/2012/07/spring-security-part-1-sample-login.html